# Floating point division in X86 assembly gives weird result

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, fasm

I'm currently studying [Simply FPU tutorial](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html). So as exercise for myself, I'd like to learn how to divide floating points in assembly. Let's say I'm going to divide 48.6 by 17.1. Here's the code.

```
format PE console 4.0
entry main
include 'win32a.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable
num1 dq 48.6
num2 dq 17.1
result dq ?
fmt db "%g", 10
szBuff db 32 dup (0)

section '.code' code readable executable
main:
fld qword [num1]
fld qword [num2]
fdivp 
fstp qword [result]
invoke printf, fmt, result 
invoke ExitProcess, 0


section '.idata' import data readable
library kernel32,'kernel32.dll', msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
import kernel32, ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'
```

The output of the code is

> 7.62883e+265

What goes wrong here?

As suggested by Jester, I examined the code using OllyDbg

[image: ollydbg screenshot]

I guess the result was correct, but somehow it was messed up by printf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upvote for using that tutorial, it's very good :)

A couple problems there:

- your values will not be `st(0)` and `st(7)` they will be `st(1)` and `st(0)`. The register numbering is fixed, it's always `st(0)` at the top, but the barrel turns. When you load something it will be `st(0)`. If you load something else afterwards, the barrel rotates, and what you previously had will move to `st(1)` and the current value will be put in `st(0)`.
- make sure your assembler generates the proper-sized instructions,
  such as for the `fld` and the `fst`
- make sure your `invoke` macro knows how to pass floating point
  arguments to `printf`
- you are not cleaning up the FPU stack (doesn't affect operation here,
  it's just a general problem)

I recommend you use a debugger to single step the code, so you can see what's happening and you don't even need to mess with trying to use `printf`.

---

**Update**: sample session using gdb on linux with a working code (edited for clarity):

```
$ cat > div.s
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl main

.data
num1: .double 48.6
num2: .double 17.1
fmt: .string "%g\n"

.text
main:
    sub esp, 16
    fld qword ptr [num1]    # st(0)=48.6
    fld qword ptr [num2]    # st(0)=17.1, st(1)=48.6
    fdivp                   # st(0)=st(1)/st(0), one item popped
    fstp qword ptr [esp+4]  # store as argument and pop
    mov dword ptr [esp], offset fmt
    call printf
    add esp, 16
    ret
$ gcc -masm=intel -m32 -g div.s -o div
$ ./div
2.84211
$ gdb ./div
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20111117-cvs-debian
(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483c4: file div.s, line 11.
(gdb) r
Starting program: div 
Breakpoint 1, main () at div.s:11
11          sub esp, 16
(gdb) n
main () at div.s:12
12          fld qword ptr [num1]    # st(0)=48.6
(gdb) 
13          fld qword ptr [num2]    # st(0)=17.1, st(1)=48.6
(gdb) info float
=>R7: Valid   0x4004c266666666666800 +48.60000000000000142      
  R6: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R5: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R4: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R3: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R2: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R1: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R0: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
(gdb) n
14          fdivp                   # st(0)=st(1)/st(0), one item popped
(gdb) info float
  R7: Valid   0x4004c266666666666800 +48.60000000000000142      
=>R6: Valid   0x400388ccccccccccd000 +17.10000000000000142      
  R5: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R4: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R3: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R2: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R1: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R0: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
(gdb) n
15          fstp qword ptr [esp+4]  # store as argument and pop
(gdb) info float
=>R7: Valid   0x4000b5e50d79435e4e16 +2.842105263157894584      
  R6: Empty   0x400388ccccccccccd000
  R5: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R4: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R3: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R2: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R1: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R0: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
(gdb) n
16          mov dword ptr [esp], offset fmt
(gdb) info float
  R7: Empty   0x4000b5e50d79435e4e16
  R6: Empty   0x400388ccccccccccd000
  R5: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R4: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R3: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R2: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
  R1: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
=>R0: Empty   0x00000000000000000000
```

Note that `gdb` prints the instruction that's gonna be executed next. The FPU stack top is marked by the arrow, that's always `st(0)` by definition. It is followed by the others in increasing order and wraparound if necessary. The first dump shows `48.6` being loaded into `st(0)` because that's marked by the arrow, the other locations are empty. Then, `17.1` is being loaded into `st(0)` again because the arrow has moved (the barrel rotated). The `48.6` is now `st(1)`. `FDIVP` performs the division and removes one item from the stack, so we end up with result in `st(0)` and the rest empty. `FSTP` then stores `st(0)` for the `printf` as argument and removes it from the stack, so all registers are now empty.

Comment: Hi Jester, thanks for the hint. Now I got the correct result, but somehow it didn't printed properly. I'll have to study my code again.

Comment: As seen in your disassembly, the `invoke printf, fmt, result` macro call puts the address of `result` on the stack, and not `result` itself which `printf` expects.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This part: "invoke printf, fmt, result", should be replaced with "cinvoke printf, fmt, double [result]. FASM has a macro called cinvoke used for calling C functions, and double is the C equivalent of qword. I put the corrected version here: http://pastebin.com/11hXKwdF, so people can see the difference :)